# Pass Lat/Lng to onPostExecute in android

Tags: android, google-maps

i'm trying to create a google map in android from json but can't get the latlng values in onPostExecute from AsyncTask. i'm new to it .
Here is my code.

```
 // Declare Variables
 JSONObject jsonobject;
 JSONArray jsonarray;
 ListView listview;
 ListViewAdapter adapter;
 ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
 static String ID="id";
 static String NAME = "name";
 static String LAT="lat";
static String LNG="lng";



@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("https://sitename.com/storeListJson.php");

        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("contacts");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Retrive JSON Objects
                map.put("id", jsonobject.getString("id"));
                map.put("name", jsonobject.getString("name"));

                map.put("lat",jsonobject.getString("lat"));
                map.put("lng",jsonobject.getString("lng"));

                String latt=jsonobject.getString(LAT);
                String lngg=jsonobject.getString(LNG);

                // Set the JSON Objects into the arrayddf
            //  arraylist.add(map);



                Log.d("Location", "Location:" + latt + " " +  lngg);
                //above line shows me the lat/lng values quite right in logcat 

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }



    @Override    

    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {


    //what to write here, tried all things but cant get lat/lng vals


    }
```

i tried a lot of methods and usually get blank map followed by NPE error cause onPostExecute the lat/lng values are missing.

```
Log.d("Location", "Location:" + latt + " " +  lngg);
```

above line shows me the lat/lng values quite right in logcat which i execute in doInBackground.

i am new to android stuff and hope SO community will help me in directing me to right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass the values of latt and lngg instead of null in your `doInBackground()` method.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // Create an array
    arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
    jsonobject = JSONfunctions
            .getJSONfromURL("https://sitename.com/storeListJson.php");

    try {
        // Locate the array name in JSON
        jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("contacts");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
            // Retrive JSON Objects
            map.put("id", jsonobject.getString("id"));
            map.put("name", jsonobject.getString("name"));

            map.put("lat",jsonobject.getString("lat"));
            map.put("lng",jsonobject.getString("lng"));

            String latt=jsonobject.getString(LAT);
            String lngg=jsonobject.getString(LNG);

            // Set the JSON Objects into the arrayddf
            arraylist.add(map);


            Log.d("Location", "Location:" + latt + " " +  lngg);
            //above line shows me the lat/lng values quite right in logcat 

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return arraylist;
}



@Override    

protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results)
{
     //Do what you want with the results here

}
```

You're also going to have to go to the part where you extend `AsyncTask` and change it so it also includes the `arraylist`, something like `extends AsyncTask<String, null, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>`

Comment: Thanks for guidance . i have been able to get the lat/lng inside the onPostExecute (LogCat shows all entries) . However when i try to plot a map, nothing happens .
`setUpMap();
    for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
                   
  double lattDouble = Double.parseDouble(arraylist.get(i).get(LAT));

  double longDouble =Double.parseDouble(arraylist.get(i).get(LNG));
                  
  Log.d("Location", "Location:" + lattDouble + " " +  longDouble);

   gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lattDouble,longDouble))); `

I See no marker and logcat shows 1 latlng

Comment: I have finally been able to show the map with markers. I have been calling mapIntialize function at two places with the second one with code statements. Perhaps forgot that i had called it twice. Thank you very much for the support. OS Community rocks!

Comment: can ya please direct me to or guide me how can I show only those 20 places which fit in some radius limit from the user.
I know it will need location listener but don't have an idea where to start from.

Comment: There are probably several times ways to do this. Some guides about advanced map features here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/#spherical Also, the documentation for location is quite good: https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Comment: @Shadesblade i need help in google maps v2, i need to pass the value of LatLng using json parsing to the jsonarray having json object LatLng . can yu pls guide me